# overriding method based on SDK version

Tags: ios, ios9

I am testing my app on Xcode 7 which is throwing me a warning for supportedInterfaceOrientations method. Prior to Xcode 7, the return type of this method was NSUInteger. Now it is UIInterfaceOrientationMask. What can I do so that it works for previous SDKs as well as the new one? I have done something like this:(I am not sure if this is the proper way)

```
#ifdef __IPHONE_9_0
- (UIInterfaceOrientationMask)supportedInterfaceOrientations
#else
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
#endif
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
}
```

Comment: This is the proper way. I would do one define and typedef inside of it, so you can keep ifdefs to a minimum

Comment: Thanks for the input! Shall try out your suggestion.